# Can we disable the alert icon in Experience editor on Condition?

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, workflow

In Experience Editor we get the below alert bar where we can change the state and other workflow related changes, is there a way to **disable it for some pages**:
[image]

Comment: Do you want any specific alert to hide or you want it for all types of alerts?

Comment: I want it if it is for Workflow only if that is possible, I am not able find the root how it works. It seems to be dynamic binding to js

Comment: If it can be disable for few Roles that also will do, Please suggest any possible solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore's `getPageEditorNotifications` pipeline is responsible to show the alert in Experience Editor. I will not recommend hiding the notification in Experience Editor but if it is your requirement then you need to add your condition by creating a `processor` class which will inherit the `GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor` or as per your requirement you can override the process method of `GetWorkflowNotification` processor for showing the workflow notification only if the current user is not in a specific role.

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class RoleBasedWorkflowNotification : GetWorkflowNotification
    {
        public override void Process(GetPageEditorNotificationsArgs arguments)
        {
            //Your condition to check the user
            if (!Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole("sitecore\\customrole"))
            {
                base.Process(arguments);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and after that, you need to patch your code as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery or Reporting or Processing">
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="ExperienceEditor" name="ExperienceEditor">
        <pipelines>
          <getPageEditorNotifications>
            <processor 
              type="YourNameSpace.RoleBasedWorkflowNotification, YourNameSpace" 
               patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.GetWorkflowNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor']" />
          </getPageEditorNotifications>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It worked for my scenario, Thank you!!